# Character array without a null terminator in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, undefined-behavior, null-terminated

Sometimes I am using sequences of characters (strings) except the null terminator is not needed or wanted, for example if I am using `memcpy()` and the length is already known. A such, I prefer to omit the null terminator. A cumbersome way to do this would be declaring an array:

```
char no_term[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

However, I would prefer to use quoted strings, as these are much more efficient to program with. However quoted strings automatically include a null terminator at the end. But would **specifying the array size to exclude the null terminator invoke undefined behavior**? Is the following **valid C**, as long as I do not use these where a null terminated string is required (e.g., passing them to `strlen()`)?

```
char no_term[5] = "hello";
char no_term_array[3][3] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

Comment: Code such as `char no_term[5] = "hello";` ***will*** get you whatever "You broke the build!" award/hat/dunce cap often enough your org will engrave your name on it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle However, even if 99% of the time code such as that is caused by programmers who do not know what they are doing, the question is, is this valid C, if I *do* know what I am doing?

Comment: It doesn't matter if *you* know what you're doing - it's the other programmers who have to work on the code over its entire lifetime that are not going to catch the fact that your `char` array is **not** a string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I could put an in code comment explaining that the lack of a null terminator is deliberate

Comment: One drawback to this is that humans are fallible, and counting characters is tedious and error prone. What is the size (without '\0') of "Supercalifragilisticexpialidotious" ?(sp??)

Comment: @Fe2O3 How about a macro function? `#define NO_NULL_TERM(string_literal) (const char[sizeof(string_literal)-1]){string_literal}`

Comment: @user16217248 Or a VLA perhaps... (Can't try it... Old compiler...) `:-)`

Comment: @user16217248 Yeah, or a similar macro to define a named object. The problem with `const` compound literals is you can't quite be sure the compiler will make them `static` and you'd often want something like this to be `static`. (Alas, compound literals aren't allowed to be marked `static`, for reasons unknown).

Comment: @user16217248 What would happen if `string_literal` was ""? My brain hurts thinking about it...

Comment: @Fe2O3 How would a zero length array compound literal behave? I do not know

Comment: @Fe2O3 and user16217248 -- C doesn't allow zero length arrays: [_"An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects...."_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20)

Comment: @adabsurdum Another reason why resorting to macro "functions" is left to the brave and the foolish `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [§6.7.9 ¶14 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14), arrays of character type may be initialized from a string literal, even if there is no room for the terminating null character.

So yes, your posted code is valid and will not invoke undefined behavior.

Note however that this is only legal in C, not C++. In C++, there must be room for a terminating null character.

Comment: But the resultant variable is not a C string, because it has no NUL terminator. It's just an array, and it *is* undefined behaviour to *handle* it as if it is a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is why I said 'character array' in the title instead of 'string'

Comment: Yes, it is strictly true that the *posted code* will not be undefined behaviour but is slightly misleading, hence the comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane the question specifically asks for an array that will not be handled like a null-terminated string

Comment: It would have been nice if the Standard had provided a syntax to indicate whether the contents of a string literal were expected to completely fill a space, be exactly one byte shorter than a space, be at least one byte shorter than a space, or have an arbitrary size relationship with a space.  In many cases, a programmer will expect one of those things, and it would be useful to have a diagnostic any time the expectation is violated.